# get path of uploaded picture for custom parallax effect

Tags: theming, 8, blocks, media

i created a custom block where i can upload an image. i overwrite the custom block with a template:

```
   <div{{ attributes }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if label %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}
  {% block content %}
   <div{{ content_attributes.addClass( 'content') }}>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

          {{content.field_parallax_bilder }}  <----- (1)

          <div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="(2)">  <----- (2)

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>

  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

i want to get the path of the image (1) and include it in my data-image-src parameter (2). is there an easier way then write a block_preprocess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set a $src var from the corresponding preprocess hook.

```
function myModuleOrTheme_preprocess_block(&$variables){

if(isset($variables['elements']['content']['field_parralaxBgImage']))
//or any other way to test if you are in the right block

   //Get the Image id : 
   $imgListItems = $variables['elements']['content']['field_testimages']['#items'];
   $imgId = $imgListItems->getValue()[0]['target_id']; 
   //load the entity :
   $image = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($imageId);

  // now you can simply return the original image's url : 
  $variables['parralaxBgSrc'] = image->url();

  //or return a styled image's url (croped or resized) with a image style configured in the BO
  $imageStyle = \Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle::load('imageStyle_id');
  $variables['parralaxBgSrc'] = $imageStyle->buildUrl($image->getFileUri());

}
```

After that, you'll be able to use it in your twig tpl :

```
 <div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="{{$parralaxBgSrc}}">
```

(Dont forgot to flush your cache after adding the hook)

Et voila! :)